# Creating a thread inside a child process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

To my understanding, a thread is a unit under a process. So if I use the multi-threading library in python, it would create the threads under the main process (correct me if im wrong since im still learning). But is there a way to create threads under a different process or child process? So is it possible to multithread in a process since a process has its own shared memory. Lets say an example, i have an application which needs to run in parallel with 3 process. In each process, i want it to run concurrently and share the same memory space. If let's say this is possible, does this mean i need to have a threading code inside my function so that when i run the function with a different process, it will create its own thread?

P.s: I know the gil locks a thread in a process but what im curious is it even possible for a process to create its own thread.

Also its not specifically for python. I just want to know in general about this

Answer (score 3):

Try not to confuse threads and processes. In python, a process is effectively a separate program with its own copy of the python interpreter (at least on platforms that use method *spawn* to create new processes, such as Window). These are created with the `multiprocessing` library.

A process can have one or more threads. These share the same memory and can share global variables. These are created with the `threading` library.

Its perfectly acceptable to create a separate process, and have that process create several threads (although it may be harder to manage as the program grows in size).

As you mentioned the GIL, it does not affect process as they each have their own GIL. Threads within a process are affected by the GIL but they do drop the lock at various points which allows your `threading.Thread` code to effectively run "concurrently".

> But is there a way to create threads under a different process or child process?

Yes

> In each process, I want it to run concurrently and share the same memory space.

If you are using separate processes, they do not share the same memory. You need to use an object like a `multiprocessing.Queue` to transfer data between the processes or shared memory structures such as `multiprocessing.Array`.

> does this mean I need to have a threading code inside my function so that when I run the function with a different process, it will create its own thread?

Yes

Comment: I see. Thanks for answering. Reason why i got curious of this is, well i understand GIL locks the thread and each process has a GIL of its own but lets say you have a program and you run like 4 functions each on a different process which you want it to run concurrently, if we child process of that, its gonna be harder to share the variables and objects created in the function but if we use threads then we could share it with each other plus there is less overhead in creating threads than process.

Comment: Sounds about right. The simplest way of choosing threads vs processes is that threads are best for IO limited tasks (waiting for responses from external sources) and multiprocessing is best for CPU limited tasks (crunching numbers).